# Шахматная доска - одной формулой

Tags: javascript, svg, математика

Замечал, что в шахматных задачках часто рисуют доску через условие, - если остаток от деления на 8 равен 0, то не меняют цвет. Чисто из спортивного интереса, захотелось найти решение через одну формулу. Оно нашлось, но пока не покажу.

Может найдутся разные прикольные решения. Краткость - не главное. Допускается использование встроенных JS функций.

[( Fiddle )](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/o6qn9vhj/)

```js
let board = document.getElementById('board');

let color = ["white", "black"];
// Задумка была в том, чтобы выводить 0 или 1, в зависимости от нужного цвета.

for( let i = 0; i < 64; i++ ){
  let cell = document.createElement('div');
  let index = ( i % 2 ); // Ваша формула
  cell.className = 'cell ' + color[ index ];
  board.appendChild( cell );
}
```

```css
#board {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 0 0 18px #fff1ba,
    inset 0 0 0 20px #800,
    1px 1px 5px 1px #000;
}
.cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.black {
  background-image: url('https://gyazo.com/2ab3718369a23d98cf4cb8f74d1af7e4.png');
}
.white {
  background-image: url('https://gyazo.com/1b53d5bd1715435422adeea81a5fbf73.png');
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Answer (score 13):

Побитовый сдвиг на 3 вправо = целочисленное деление на 2^3 или 8 без остатка, 
таким образом получим номер строки, прибавляем к этому текущий индекс и выясняем четное или нечетное число.

```
let index = ((i>>3) + i) % 2;
```

```js
let color = ["white", "black"];
for( let i = 0; i < 64; i++ ) {
  let index = ((i>>3) + i) % 2; 
  board.innerHTML += `<div class='cell ${color[index]}'></div>`
}
```

```css
#board {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #0005;
}
.cell {
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 12.5%;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
.white {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Сумма координат клетки четна - клетка белая, нечетна черная.

```
let index = (Math.floor(i/8)+ i % 8)%2;
```

Comment: `( i % 2 + Math.floor( i / 8 % 2) ) % 2;` — и у меня был почти такой же)

Comment: на самом деле этот вариант мог быть таким `( i + Math.floor(i/8) )%2`

Comment: Стараюсь, чтобы выражение было максимально понятно для человека. Компьютеру-то все равно)

Answer (score 8):

### Svg Pattern

Можно использовать pattern для заполнения прямоугольника шахматными квадратами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=875) и [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/pattern)

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="320" height="320" viewBox="0 0 32 32" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
 <pattern id="ptn1"
   x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
             <g fill="#A97641"  fill-opacity="0.7">  
            <rect  x="0" y="0" width="4" height="4" />
             <rect x="4" y="4" width="4" height="4" />
    </g>
  </pattern>    
</defs>

<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#ptn1)" />
</svg>
```

Немного не по теме, но может быть полезно при заполнении любой фигуры.

Например заполнение контура рисунка зебры:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1" x="0" y="0" width="792" height="612" viewBox="0 0 792 612">
<defs>
<pattern id="ptn1"
   x="0" y="0" width="40" height="20"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">   
             <g fill="black"  fill-opacity="0.7">  
            <rect  x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" />
             <rect x="20" y="20" width="20" height="20" />
    </g>
  </pattern>  
</defs>
<path stroke="#000000" fill="url(#ptn1)" stroke-width="3" d="M259 310c2 4 4 8 6 11 6 12 13 20 16 29 3 9 3 19 2 30 -1 11-3 23-4 33 -1 10-2 17-2 25 0 8 0 17-1 25s-3 15-6 21c-3 6-6 10-10 14 -4 4-9 8-12 11 -4 4-7 8-9 12 -2 4-2 8-1 10s5 3 11 4c5 0 13 1 17-1 4-2 6-5 8-9 2-4 5-8 9-10 3-2 7-1 9-4 2-3 2-10 4-20 2-10 4-22 8-33 4-11 9-19 13-27 3-8 5-15 6-15 2 0 3 9 5 22 2 13 4 31 4 46 0 15-2 28-6 36s-10 11-14 17c-4 6-7 14-9 20 -1 6-1 10 0 13 2 3 5 4 10 5 6 1 14 1 19 0 5-1 8-4 9-6 1-3 0-6 1-9 1-3 2-7 6-10 3-3 8-7 10-12 2-5 1-13 1-22 -1-8-1-18 0-28 1-10 4-21 6-28 2-7 3-10 2-17 -1-7-3-17-4-27 -1-10-2-21-1-30 1-9 4-15 8-20 4-4 10-7 22-7 12 0 31 2 50 5s37 5 58 3c21-2 43-9 57-13 14-5 19-7 24-2 6 5 12 18 18 32 6 15 11 31 13 46 3 15 4 28 2 41 -2 13-7 26-11 33 -4 8-9 11-12 14 -4 4-7 8-9 12 -2 4-3 9-3 12 0 3 0 4 3 5s9 2 15 2c6 0 12 0 15-3 4-3 5-8 5-12 1-4 1-7 4-8s8-2 11-3c4-1 6-3 6-7 1-4-1-11-1-19 0-8 1-17 4-29 2-12 6-26 9-35 2-9 3-14 2-19 -1-6-2-13-5-19 -3-7-7-13-9-19 -2-6-2-10 4-6 5 5 15 19 25 35 10 16 21 35 28 48 7 13 9 21 10 34s2 29 0 41 -6 20-8 26c-2 6-3 9-2 12 1 3 5 5 10 6 5 1 12 1 17 0 5-1 9-3 10-7s-1-8-1-14 3-11 4-16c2-5 2-9 2-13 0-4-2-9-4-19 -2-10-5-24-7-39 -1-15-1-31-1-41 0-10-1-14-7-22 -6-8-17-20-23-36 -6-15-8-34-7-52 0-3 6-21 7-42 1-17-1-39-1-39 18-10 14 80 13 89 -1 11 2 21 4 30 3 11 32 71 35 44 1-7 2-18 2-27s-2-15-6-24c-3-9-8-20-12-31s-6-21-6-30c-1-24-7-60-21-79 -13-17-41-39-55-44 -13-5-4-1-6-2 -6-2-12-4-19-5 -21-4-49-5-87-2 -37 3-84 10-117 13 -32 3-50 1-66 0 -8 0-15 0-22 0 -1-1-2-2-3-3 -1-2-1-6-3-6 -1-1-4 1-6 1 -2 0-3-3-3-5 0-3 0-6-2-6 -1 0-4 3-6 4 -2 0-2-2-2-5 -1-3-1-7-2-9 -1-1-2 0-3 3s-3 6-4 7c-1 0-2-3-3-6 -1-4-2-8-4-9 -1 0-3 4-5 7 -1 3-2 5-3 3 -1-1-1-6-3-11 -1-4-3-9-4-10 -1-1-1 1-2 5 0 4-1 10-1 12 -1 2-2 0-4-5 -2-4-5-10-8-15 -3-4-6-7-8-7 -1 0-1 2 0 6 1 4 1 9 0 10 -1 1-4-2-6-5 -3-3-5-7-9-10 -3-3-7-6-8-6 -1 1 0 5 0 8 0 3 0 6-1 6 -1-1-3-4-5-9 -2-4-5-8-8-11 -2-2-4-2-5 0 -1 3 0 8-1 9 -1 1-4-3-7-7 -3-4-6-8-9-10 -3-2-4-3-5-1 -1 2-1 8-3 8 -2 0-5-5-9-9 -4-4-8-7-9-7 -1 0 1 4 2 8 1 4 2 8-1 7 -3-1-9-8-14-12 -5-4-8-4-9-3 -1 2 1 5-1 5 -2 0-9-5-14-8 -3-1-5-2-6-3 -5-8-11-17-17-23 -9-9-18-15-24-16 -5-2-7 0-7 5 -1 5-1 13 2 21 3 9 8 19 15 30 1 1 2 2 2 4 -5-2-11-5-17-8 -10-5-19-11-26-17 -7-6-12-11-16-14 -4-3-8-4-10-1 -1 3 0 11 3 19 3 8 9 17 15 24 6 7 13 12 19 16 6 4 12 6 17 8l0 0c-7 9-14 21-18 29 -5 10-6 15-6 20 0 5 3 9 3 15 0 7-2 16-4 25 -2 10-5 20-9 26 -3 6-7 9-7 13 0 4 3 9 7 17 4 7 7 17 14 22 4 4 8 2 12 3 12 3 22 0 27-7 20-24 11-14 31-26 7-4 14-9 18-14 4-5 6-9 9-10 3-1 7 1 15 6 8 5 21 14 33 22 12 8 24 16 33 25C251 298 256 304 259 310z"/>
</svg>
```

Поворачиваем рисунок зебры - `patternTransform="rotate(30)"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1" x="0" y="0" width="792" height="612" viewBox="0 0 792 612">
<defs>
<pattern id="ptn1"
   x="0" y="0" width="40" height="20"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
             patternTransform="rotate(30)">   
             <g fill="black"  fill-opacity="0.7">  
            <rect  x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" />
             <rect x="20" y="20" width="20" height="20" />
    </g>
  </pattern>  
</defs>
<path stroke="#000000" fill="url(#ptn1)" stroke-width="3" d="M259 310c2 4 4 8 6 11 6 12 13 20 16 29 3 9 3 19 2 30 -1 11-3 23-4 33 -1 10-2 17-2 25 0 8 0 17-1 25s-3 15-6 21c-3 6-6 10-10 14 -4 4-9 8-12 11 -4 4-7 8-9 12 -2 4-2 8-1 10s5 3 11 4c5 0 13 1 17-1 4-2 6-5 8-9 2-4 5-8 9-10 3-2 7-1 9-4 2-3 2-10 4-20 2-10 4-22 8-33 4-11 9-19 13-27 3-8 5-15 6-15 2 0 3 9 5 22 2 13 4 31 4 46 0 15-2 28-6 36s-10 11-14 17c-4 6-7 14-9 20 -1 6-1 10 0 13 2 3 5 4 10 5 6 1 14 1 19 0 5-1 8-4 9-6 1-3 0-6 1-9 1-3 2-7 6-10 3-3 8-7 10-12 2-5 1-13 1-22 -1-8-1-18 0-28 1-10 4-21 6-28 2-7 3-10 2-17 -1-7-3-17-4-27 -1-10-2-21-1-30 1-9 4-15 8-20 4-4 10-7 22-7 12 0 31 2 50 5s37 5 58 3c21-2 43-9 57-13 14-5 19-7 24-2 6 5 12 18 18 32 6 15 11 31 13 46 3 15 4 28 2 41 -2 13-7 26-11 33 -4 8-9 11-12 14 -4 4-7 8-9 12 -2 4-3 9-3 12 0 3 0 4 3 5s9 2 15 2c6 0 12 0 15-3 4-3 5-8 5-12 1-4 1-7 4-8s8-2 11-3c4-1 6-3 6-7 1-4-1-11-1-19 0-8 1-17 4-29 2-12 6-26 9-35 2-9 3-14 2-19 -1-6-2-13-5-19 -3-7-7-13-9-19 -2-6-2-10 4-6 5 5 15 19 25 35 10 16 21 35 28 48 7 13 9 21 10 34s2 29 0 41 -6 20-8 26c-2 6-3 9-2 12 1 3 5 5 10 6 5 1 12 1 17 0 5-1 9-3 10-7s-1-8-1-14 3-11 4-16c2-5 2-9 2-13 0-4-2-9-4-19 -2-10-5-24-7-39 -1-15-1-31-1-41 0-10-1-14-7-22 -6-8-17-20-23-36 -6-15-8-34-7-52 0-3 6-21 7-42 1-17-1-39-1-39 18-10 14 80 13 89 -1 11 2 21 4 30 3 11 32 71 35 44 1-7 2-18 2-27s-2-15-6-24c-3-9-8-20-12-31s-6-21-6-30c-1-24-7-60-21-79 -13-17-41-39-55-44 -13-5-4-1-6-2 -6-2-12-4-19-5 -21-4-49-5-87-2 -37 3-84 10-117 13 -32 3-50 1-66 0 -8 0-15 0-22 0 -1-1-2-2-3-3 -1-2-1-6-3-6 -1-1-4 1-6 1 -2 0-3-3-3-5 0-3 0-6-2-6 -1 0-4 3-6 4 -2 0-2-2-2-5 -1-3-1-7-2-9 -1-1-2 0-3 3s-3 6-4 7c-1 0-2-3-3-6 -1-4-2-8-4-9 -1 0-3 4-5 7 -1 3-2 5-3 3 -1-1-1-6-3-11 -1-4-3-9-4-10 -1-1-1 1-2 5 0 4-1 10-1 12 -1 2-2 0-4-5 -2-4-5-10-8-15 -3-4-6-7-8-7 -1 0-1 2 0 6 1 4 1 9 0 10 -1 1-4-2-6-5 -3-3-5-7-9-10 -3-3-7-6-8-6 -1 1 0 5 0 8 0 3 0 6-1 6 -1-1-3-4-5-9 -2-4-5-8-8-11 -2-2-4-2-5 0 -1 3 0 8-1 9 -1 1-4-3-7-7 -3-4-6-8-9-10 -3-2-4-3-5-1 -1 2-1 8-3 8 -2 0-5-5-9-9 -4-4-8-7-9-7 -1 0 1 4 2 8 1 4 2 8-1 7 -3-1-9-8-14-12 -5-4-8-4-9-3 -1 2 1 5-1 5 -2 0-9-5-14-8 -3-1-5-2-6-3 -5-8-11-17-17-23 -9-9-18-15-24-16 -5-2-7 0-7 5 -1 5-1 13 2 21 3 9 8 19 15 30 1 1 2 2 2 4 -5-2-11-5-17-8 -10-5-19-11-26-17 -7-6-12-11-16-14 -4-3-8-4-10-1 -1 3 0 11 3 19 3 8 9 17 15 24 6 7 13 12 19 16 6 4 12 6 17 8l0 0c-7 9-14 21-18 29 -5 10-6 15-6 20 0 5 3 9 3 15 0 7-2 16-4 25 -2 10-5 20-9 26 -3 6-7 9-7 13 0 4 3 9 7 17 4 7 7 17 14 22 4 4 8 2 12 3 12 3 22 0 27-7 20-24 11-14 31-26 7-4 14-9 18-14 4-5 6-9 9-10 3-1 7 1 15 6 8 5 21 14 33 22 12 8 24 16 33 25C251 298 256 304 259 310z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 8):

Еще один вариант, слегка запутанный, но претендент на самый короткий.

```
let index = 9/8*i&1;
```

---

Как это работает:

последним применяется `&1` **побитовое И с единицей** - по сути возвращает последний бит от двоичного представления числа - т.е для четных чисел вернется 0 для нечетных 1.

перед этим индекс умножается коэффициент- `9/8*i` - это уже упрощенная запись от `i/8 + i`, тут индекс строки `i/8` (дробную часть отбросит побитовый оператор) складывается с индексом ячейки `i`.

т.е. до упрощения это выглядело бы так:

```
let index = (i/8 + i)&1
```

Если сложить все это вместе получится все та же формула... как и в других ответах

```js
for (let i=0; i<64; i++)  
  document.body.innerHTML += `<cell style='opacity:${9/8*i&1}'></cell>`
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #0005;
}
cell {
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 12.5%;
  background-color: black;
}
```