# Задача: построить шахматную доску на js

Tags: javascript

Господа, помогите понять, как решать задачу по построению шахматной доски на js.

```js
var slash = '#';
var space = ' ';
var result = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    if (j % 2 == 0) {
      result += space;
    } else {
      result += slash;
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

Сейчас:

1. Я понимаю, как и почему отрисовывается первая строка шахматной доски.
2. Я не понимаю, как обнулить предыдущие значения result для следующей строки.
3. Я не понимаю, как прописать условия для каждой четной строки result, чтобы пробелы и # менялись местами.
4. Я не понимаю, как в цикле происходит переход на новую строку.
5. Собственно, я не могу понять, как решить эту задачу.

Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1014047/188366

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Я не понимаю, как обнулить предыдущие значения result для следующей строки.*

В конце цикла присвоить пустую строку

*Я не понимаю, как прописать условия для каждой четной строки result, чтобы пробелы и # менялись местами.*

Сделать переменную которая через ряд то 0, то 1

```js
var slash = '#';
var space = ' ';
var result = '';
var row = true;
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    if ((j+row) % 2 == 0) {
      result += space;
    } else {
      result += slash;
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
  result='';
  row = ! row;
}
```

можно немного короче

```js
var full = ' # # # # ';
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   console.log('<'+full.substr(i%2,8)+'>')
```

Comment: я до короткого стиля не дошел)))
Спасибо, а булево row при сложении с цифрой превращается в 0 или 1 соответственно? Я почему-то думал, что булево значение приводит другую переменную к булеву значению(

Comment: нет, арифметика вполне с булевым типом правильно работает - false 0, true 1. Я пока не знаю языка, в котором не так. Это особенно удобно для функций типа sum()

Answer (score 1):

```js
const BLACK = "#"
const WHITE = "."

var n = 8
var res = ""

for (var q=0; q<n; ++q) {
  var line = ""
  
  for (var w=0; w<n; ++w) {
    line += q+w & 1 ? BLACK : WHITE
  }
  
  res += line + "\n"
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
     function chessBoard(count, number, rows, symbolOne, symbolTwo) {
        if (count >= number) {return;}
        else {
           if (isNaN(count) === false && isNaN(number) === false &&  isNaN(rows) === 
           false  && typeof (count) === "number" && typeof (number) === "number" 
             &&typeof (rows) === "number"  && typeof (symbolOne) === "string" && 
              typeof (symbolTwo) === "string") {
                var exe = "";
                for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
                    for (var j = 1; j <= rows; j++) {
                        exe += (i + j) % 2 === 0 ? symbolOne : symbolTwo;
                    }
                    exe += '\n';
                }
    
                console.log(exe);
                count++;
                return chessBoard(count, number, rows, symbolOne, symbolTwo);
            }
           else {
               console.error("One of the parameters is not correct!");
           }
        }
     }
     var board = chessBoard(0, 1, 5, "▦ ", "▢ ");
     console.log(board);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]