# Как правильно закрасить клетки шахматной доски на Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

```
const chessWrap = document.createElement('div')
chessWrap.style.height = '160px'
chessWrap.style.width = '160px'
document.body.appendChild(chessWrap)

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    const item1 = document.createElement('div')
    item1.style.height = '20px'
    item1.style.width = '20px'
    item1.style.background = '#000'
    item1.style.float = 'left'
    chessWrap.appendChild(item1)
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        const item2 = document.createElement('div')
        item2.style.height = '20px'
        item2.style.width = '20px'
        item2.style.background = 'red'
        item2.style.float = 'left'
        chessWrap.appendChild(item2)
    }
}
console.log(chessWrap)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1014047/188366

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы делаете какую-нибудь игру , лучше конечно это делать через canvas. Но возможно у вас какое-то другое применение этому, я смог сделать это и таким способом.

```js
function createChess(scaleSquare,scaleCell){////scaleSquare размер поля (10х10) scaleCell размер клетки в пикселях(20px x 20px)
  const chessWrap = document.createElement('div');
    chessWrap.style.height = scaleSquare * scaleCell + 'px';///// узнаём новую высоту поля
    chessWrap.style.width = scaleSquare * scaleCell + 'px';///// узнаём новую ширину поля
    chessWrap.style.display = 'flex';/// Добавил флексы
    chessWrap.style.flexWrap = 'wrap';
    document.body.appendChild(chessWrap);
    

    for (let i = 0; i < scaleSquare; i++) { 
      for (let j = 0; j < scaleSquare; j++) {  ////// идёт перебор всего поля (10 x 10)
        const item = document.createElement('div');
        item.style.height = scaleCell +'px';
        item.style.width = scaleCell +'px'; //// подставляем размеры из переменной scaleCell
        if((i+j)%2===0 ){ //Формула отвечающая за чередование
          item.style.background = '#000';
        }else{
          item.style.background = 'red'
        }
         chessWrap.appendChild(item);
          
      }
  }
}
createChess(10,20)
createChess(10,10)
createChess(8,30)
```

Comment: спасибо большое сейчас попробуем

Comment: Вы можете запустить скрипт прям в stackoverflow

Comment: да вроде норм, спасибо, а как мне все это засунуть в функцию и когда передать туда число 10 он мне нарисовал доску 10 на 10

Comment: нужно математически высчитывать размер всего полотна, и каждой клетки.
Сейчас попробую написать такую функцию

Comment: спасибо большое очень сильно помогли

Comment: @ВиталикСычев , всё . Не забывайте ставить галочку если ответ на ваш вопрос верный

Comment: оооо спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
function renderChess(n, w = 20) {
        const chessWrap = document.createElement('div');
        chessWrap.style.display = 'flex'; /// Добавил флексы
        chessWrap.style.flexWrap = 'wrap';
        document.body.appendChild(chessWrap);

        const size = n * w;
        chessWrap.style.width = `${size}px`;

        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                const item = document.createElement('div');
                item.style.height = `${w}px`;
                item.style.width = `${w}px`;
                if ((i + j) % 2 === 0) {
                    //Формула отвечающая за чередование
                    item.style.background = '#000';
                } else {
                    item.style.background = 'red';
                }
                chessWrap.appendChild(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

может кому понадобится